# I am to load a profile image into a database called profiles, but how i can actually display the profile on screen?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My profiles Model file:

```
function putProfileImage($user, $image)
{


    $record = array('user' => $user, 'profileimage' => $image);
    if ($this->exists($user))
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $user)->update('profiles', $record);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $user)->insert('profiles', $record);
    }
}

function getProfileImage($user)
{

    $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
            'height' => 200,
            'length' => 150
    );


    $this->db->select('*')->from('profiles')->where('user', $user);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row->profileimage; //Trying to get property of non-object error


}
```

its the getProfileimage, similar to a do_upload function where im having the most trouble

Comment: Take a look @ http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/134429/ and http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql ... Is profileimage store as a BLOB field in the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by saving to the correct image location folder

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these sites

- http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/134429
- http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql

Then follow my pseudo code below (assuming that profileimage is store as a BLOB field in the db)

Model file:

```
function putProfileImage($user, $image)
{
    // you may need to store the image type / mine type
    $record = array('user' => $user, 'profileimage' => $image);
    if ($this->exists($user))
    {
        $this->db->update('profiles', $record)->where('user', $user);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->insert('profiles', $record);
    }
}

function getProfileImage($user)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from('profiles')->where('user', $user);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row->profileimage; //Trying to get property of non-object error
    }

    return Null;
}
```

Controller - profile.php

```
function Upload()
{
    // see - Creating the Upload Form
    // @ - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html
}

function doUpload ()
{
    //see do_upload() and save with module above
    // @ - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html
}

function displayImage()
    {
        //Retrieve image id from the URI
        $imageid = $this->uri->segment(3);
        //Initialize the images model
        $this->load->model("image_model");
        //Call the model's getImage function passing the image id
        $image = $this->image_model->getProfileImage($imageid);
        if (!is_null($image)) {
            //need to know the mine type 
           // header('Content-Type: image/png');

            header ('Content-Type: image/jpg');
            imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring($image), null,100);
        }
        else{
         // load a default profile image
        }
    }

    function viewProfile(){
        //load profile detail view for users and display image
        // 18 = change to image id
        echo '<img src="<?=base_url()?>profile/displayImage/18" alt="profile"/>';

    }
```

Comment: Thanks RS for your feedback so far - I decided to create a new model and upload controller files as I as getting no-where with trying to fit what I already had into another controller I was using - I also created a new profileimages table with varchar as the data type for my image - after I now press the upload button after uploading the image I get the following error:

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Profileimages' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\core\Loader.php on line 303

Comment: Are you storing the image data into the db or the path to where the file is located on disk? If you are storing the image data then the mysql data type should be BLOB

Comment: I'm trying to upload it into the db but now it doesnt look like its happening anymore - hitting the upload button now just seems to generate this error now. may i show u the code as i'm increasingly getting lost the more time I spend at it

Comment: Add the code to http://pastebin.com/ and send me the url (include the path where the files are located and sql create statement)

Comment: Thanks R.S. - Now at the moment I am actually loading 2 controllers into the one view page - would this be considered bad practice and just get too confusing? the other controller shows the actual page I want to display and also carries a changetext function which loads data into a profiletext model. i think i should probably combine the  2 models into the one controller wouldnt that be the right way to go about it?

Comment: But i did try the upload controller on a seperate page and got the error: Unable to load the requested class: profileimages on the do_upload result page

Comment: Create a new question with all your current code and i will look at it

Comment: What version of CI are you using? Please take a moment and review the samples http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html ... These are not correct 'function HomeProfile()' (take a look at CI v2.xx constructor) and '$this->load->library('profileimages', $config);'. You dont not have a library call 'profileimages' take a look at my orignal code/ upload library sample on CI website. You seem to be mixing CI v1.xx and v2.xx

Comment: Ok i changed this '$this->load->library('upload', $config);' I'm using v2. Why is HomeProfile incorrect should there not be a capital P?

Comment: public function __construct()

Comment: why is this necessary when you have parent::__construct(); already in the first function?

Comment: I actually have an update now of some note- When I try to now upload an image it's now diplaying an error back - The upload path does not appear to be valid - so at least theres now something being displaye on screen. I decided to use the upload form and success file as u advised - so what could it now be thats preventing me from upload the file to the screen? I have my uploads folder at the same level as my views folder

Answer (score 0):

the **Trying to get property of non-object ** error means that the most likely the query did not have a result, i.e that there is no row in *profiles* table where *user=$user*.

to help you debug, you can use this command right after *$query = $this->db->get();*

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); die();
```

*$this->db->last_query();* will get the sql of the last query run, *die()* will terminate the program.